# Getting id/class knowing src of an image using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Example code

```
<img id="necklace1" class="FirstImage" src="./images/gallery/necklace1.jpg">
```

Here I only know the src. How can I get the class of the image knowing the src using jQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below for class and id

For class

```
$('img[src="./images/gallery/necklace1.jpg"']).attr('class');
```

For id

```
$('img[src="./images/gallery/necklace1.jpg"']).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

$("img[src='your src val']").attr('class') Can give the class